# MD5 hashing to post image

Tags: iphone, md5, hash, evernote

Hi 
I am using below code to post image and I want to apply MD5 hashing in this code

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 50) ;  ;
    EDAMResource *imageResource  = [[[EDAMResource alloc]init]autorelease];
    EDAMData *imageData1 =[[EDAMData alloc]initWithBodyHash:imageData
                                                       size:[imageData length] body:imageData ];

    [imageResource setData:imageData1];
    [imageResource setRecognition:imageData1];

    NSString *mime = [[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"image/jpeg" ] autorelease];

    [imageResource setMime:mime];

    NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:imageResource,nil];
    [note setResources:imageArray];
```

Is to possible to apply md5 hashing in this code and if yes then how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some sample code on github from the [iPhoneRecipeBook](https://github.com/ktakayama/iPhoneSDK-RecipeBook/blob/master/106/EvernoteSample.m) that shows how to handle MD5 hashes for Evernote.

Comment: Thanks for reply..And if I want to send audio file also then how can I do this..See my question and please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149056/evernote-api-adding-images-and-audio-with-note

Comment: [self readFileAsData:path ]  What should I pass in this method

Comment: As you can see in the source, -dataWithContentsOfFile: is called which requires a file path of the file you wish to read.

Comment: ya i am trying to add imageview.image .NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 50) ; How can I pass image.view as string because [readFileASdata take NSString as arugment]

Comment: If I am using above code It is posting image but only thumbnail images is shown in list.when I expand note it will show only text message

Comment: Why don't you just implement the MD5 handling directly into your code based on the sample?

Comment: I used like example But I dont what to paas in EDAMResource *resource = [[EDAMResource alloc]init];
  [resource autorelease];
[resource setData:[self readfileasData:???]];  and If I use like [resource  setData:imageData1] then its posting thumbnail image

Comment: I think this is starting to move away from the original topic of this question: handling of MD5 hashing. I suggest you open another question targeted at the thumbnail/image issue - the MD5 issue seems solved.

Comment: I have posted that question. But I if I dont pass file path then how I used Md5 hashing. I am just passing my own NSData without calling readFileasData...I am asking you how to pass imageview.image in this method...clear?

Comment: Don't call readFileAsData: - use the code from the sample to write your own handling of data hashing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161332/attaching-photos-with-note-using-evernote-api  This my other question..